# Using apache directory ldap in Servicemix

Tags: ldap, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have an osgi application running on Servicemix 6. I added some code that uses apache directory for ldap lookups (org.apache.directory.api.ldap).

I got an error when deploying the app in Servicemix:

```
 Unresolved constraint...
 (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.cursor)
```

Can I use this apache lib in Servicemix? How can I import it?

Or, should I use some other lib?

Comment: Can you provide complete stack trace

Comment: Q: Why not use the standard ldap client libraries from the JDK?

Comment: Yes, good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this command, which I think wraps my dependency as osgi-compatible.

```
 bundle:install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.directory.api/api-all/1.0.0-M33
```